# How to access elements in a function enviroment with a function defined in the global enviroment in R

Tags: r, environment

I currently run into an issue accessing objects from within a function environment with a function defined outside that environment.

Here's a small example:

```
# Get data
data(mtcars)

# Create selection list
selection <- list(a = 6,
                  b = 8)

# Unevaluated function
f1 <- function(){
  setDT(mtcars)[cyl == selected, ]
}

# Evaluate function within anonymous funciton
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(x){
  
  selected <- selection[[x]]
  
  f1()
  
})
```

My problem is that I cannot access the `selected` object. I always receive the following error message:

```
Error in eval(stub[[3L]], x, enclos) : object 'selected' not found
```

Does someone have an idea how I can access the `selected` object with the `f1()` function within the `lapply()` call? I guess I need to pass a certain environment to the evaluation of `f1()`. However, I couldn't come up with a solution that works yet.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It is generally bad practice to have a function reach outside of its scope to find variables, either for read-only access or modifying it or others: it renders the function non-reproducible, which cascades quickly into other areas such as troubleshooting problems. Whatever the function needs, define formal arguments (e.g., `f1 <- function(dat, selected) as.data.table(dat)[ cyl == selected,]`, use as `f1(mtcars, 4)`.)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. I agree using a formal argument would be the best way. I just added an argument `objects` to my function now, which allows me to access all objects I need as a named list and pass them to my `{data.table}` filtering calls. Thank you for reminding me of this solution!

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you wanted?

```
library(data.table)

# Get data
data(mtcars)

# Create selection list
selection <- list(a = 6,
                  b = 8)

# Unevaluated function
f1 <- function(variable){
  setDT(mtcars)[cyl == variable, ]
}

# Evaluate function within anonymous funciton
lapply(c("a", "b"), function(x){
  
  selected <- selection[[x]]
  
  f1(selected)
  
})

##output 

[[1]]
    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2: 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
4: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
5: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7: 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6

[[2]]
     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
 1: 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
 2: 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
 3: 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
 4: 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
 5: 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
 6: 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
 7: 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
 8: 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
 9: 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
10: 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
11: 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
12: 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
13: 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
14: 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I agree specifying the objects that I would like to access as a function argument seems to be a good solution for this problem.